# Compare 2 json file and copy the difference of it to another file based on 2nd file(file2.yml) | ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am trying to compare 2 json file and print the difference of it to another file via ansible but unable to do so.

I have tried Copy and ansible.utils.fact_diff modules but no luck

**file1.yml**

```
  "from": "abc@gmail.com",
  "is_enabled": "true",
  "is_local": "true",
  "is_data": "true",
  "isin_subject": "false",
```

**file2.yml**

```
  "from": "xyz@gmail.com",
  "is_enabled": "false",
  "is_local": "true",
  "is_data": "true",
  "isin_subject": "false",
```

**output: file3.yml**

```
  "from": "xyz@gmail.com",
  "is_enabled": "false",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop dict and compare:

source0.json:

```
{
"from": "abc@gmail.com",
"is_enabled": "true",
"is_local": "true",
"is_data": "true",
"isin_subject": "false"
}
```

source1.json:

```
{
    "from": "xyz@gmail.com",
    "is_enabled": "false",
    "is_local": "true",
    "is_data": "true",
    "isin_subject": "false"
}
```

play book:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    json0: "{{ lookup('file', 'source0.json') | from_json }}"
    json1: "{{ lookup('file', 'source1.json') | from_json }}"
  tasks:
    - name: diff
      set_fact: 
        diff: "{{ diff | d({}) | combine({item.key: item.value}) }}"
      loop: "{{ json1 | dict2items }}"
      when: item.value != json0[item.key]

    - name: display diff
      debug:
        msg: "{{ diff }}"
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "from": "xyz@gmail.com",
        "is_enabled": "false"
    }
}
```